# AngularJS app with ng-repeat does not display data after loading page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, internet-explorer-9

My AngularJs Application is not displaying any error, but it does not display the data in the html table.
I am using IE9. On other browser everything is ok. This is an image of my page after loading [image]

```
This is my HTML :

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tab_op_list_main table table-bordered table-striped" style="width : 98%" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr align="left">
                                <td style="width : 2%; text-align: center">#</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'Noms'; sortReverse = !sortReverse" >
                                        Noms & prenoms
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'Noms' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'Noms' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>Fonction</td>
                                <td>Departement</td>
                                <td style="width : 7%; text-align: center">GSM</td>
                                <td style="width : 7%; text-align: center">Formule</td>

                                                                <td style="width : 7%; text-align: right">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'August'; sortReverse = !sortReverse" >
                                        August                                      <span ng-show="sortType == 'August' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'August' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                                                <td style="width : 7%; text-align: right">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'September'; sortReverse = !sortReverse" >
                                        September                                       <span ng-show="sortType == 'September' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'September' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                                                <td style="width : 7%; text-align: right">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'October'; sortReverse = !sortReverse" >
                                        October                                     <span ng-show="sortType == 'October' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'October' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                                                <td style="width : 7%; text-align: right">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'November'; sortReverse = !sortReverse" >
                                        November                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'November' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'November' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                                                                                <td style="width : 9%; text-align: right">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'Total'; sortReverse = !sortReverse" >
                                        Total
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'Total' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'Total' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr align="left" style="background-color: #51647d;color: white;">
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                                                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;padding-right: 4px;text-align: right;">{{Annuaire | filter:Noms | sumOfValue:'August' | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>
                                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;padding-right: 4px;text-align: right;">{{Annuaire | filter:Noms | sumOfValue:'September' | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>
                                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;padding-right: 4px;text-align: right;">{{Annuaire | filter:Noms | sumOfValue:'October' | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>
                                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;padding-right: 4px;text-align: right;">{{Annuaire | filter:Noms | sumOfValue:'November' | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>
                                                                <!--
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;padding-right: 4px;text-align: right;">{{Annuaire | filter:Noms | sumOfValue:'July' | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;padding-right: 4px;text-align: right;">{{Annuaire | filter:Noms | sumOfValue:'August' | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;padding-right: 4px;text-align: right;">{{Annuaire | filter:Noms | sumOfValue:'September' | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>-->
                                                                <td style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;padding-right: 4px;text-align: right;">{{ 0  + getTotal('August') + getTotal('September') + getTotal('October') + getTotal('November') | filter:Noms |  noFractionCurrency:"" }}</td>
                                                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        <tbody>
                             <tr id="{{ item.Id }}" align="left" ng-repeat="item in Annuaire | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse  | filter:Noms | filter:Mouchard | filter:January |  filter:February | filter:March | filter:April | filter:May | filter:June | filter:July | filter:August | filter:September | filter:October | filter:December | filter:Total ">
                                <td style="text-align: center; padding: 8px 2px;">{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                <td><a target="_blank" href="http://intranet.perenco.net/module/staff/?id={{ item.Id }}">{{ item.Noms }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{ item.Fonction }}</td>
                                <td>{{ item.Departement }}</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center">{{ item.GSM }}</td>
                                <td>{{ item.Formule }}</td>
                                                                                                <td style="text-align: right;padding-right: 4px;">{{ item.August  | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>
                                                                <td style="text-align: right;padding-right: 4px;">{{ item.September  | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>
                                                                <td style="text-align: right;padding-right: 4px;">{{ item.October  | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>
                                                                <td style="text-align: right;padding-right: 4px;">{{ item.November  | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>

                                <td style="text-align: right;padding-right: 4px;">{{ item.Total | noFractionCurrency:"":0 }}</td>
                              </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

This is my JS code :

```
     angular.module('sortApp', []).filter('noFractionCurrency',
    [ '$filter', '$locale', function(filter, locale) {
      var currencyFilter = filter('currency');
      var formats = locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;
      return function(amount, currencySymbol) {
        var value = currencyFilter(amount, currencySymbol);
        var sep = value.indexOf(formats.DECIMAL_SEP);
        console.log(amount, value);
        if(amount >= 0) { 
          return value.substring(0, sep);
        }
        return value.substring(0, sep) + ')';
      };
    } ])
.filter('sumOfValue', function () {
     return function (data, key) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            sum = sum + parseInt(v[key]);
        });        
        return sum;
        }
}).controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'Noms'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.Noms   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

  // create the list of sushi items 
  $scope.Annuaire = [

        { Id: '', 
            Noms: '', 
            Fonction: '', 
            Departement: '', 
            GSM: '699960058' ,
            Formule: 'Postpaid' ,
            January: 0 ,
            February: 0 ,
            March: 12028.00 ,
            April: 5350.00 ,
            May: 0 ,
            June: 2735.00 ,
            July: 14866.00 ,
            August: 8166.00 ,
            September: 8414.00 ,
            October: 8633.00 ,
            November: 6891.00 ,
            December: 0 ,
            Total: 32104 },
            { Id: '', 
            Noms: '', 
            Fonction: '', 
            Departement: '', 
            GSM: '699314133' ,
            Formule: 'Postpaid' ,
            January: 0 ,
            February: 0 ,
            March: 0.00 ,
            April: 0.00 ,
            May: 0 ,
            June: 0.00 ,
            July: 0.00 ,
            August: 0.00 ,
            September: 0.00 ,
            October: 0.00 ,
            November: 0.00 ,
            December: 0 ,
            Total: 0 },
            { Id: '', 
            Noms: '', 
            Fonction: '', 
            Departement: '', 
            GSM: '694305599' ,
            Formule: 'Postpaid' ,
            January: 0 ,
            February: 0 ,
            March: 189885.00 ,
            April: 259913.00 ,
            May: 0 ,
            June: 249022.00 ,
            July: 476196.00 ,
            August: 252790.00 ,
            September: 340631.00 ,
            October: 348546.00 ,
            November: 289889.00 ,
            December: 0 ,
            Total: 1231856 },
            { Id: '', 
            Noms: '', 
            Fonction: '', 
            Departement: '', 
            GSM: '699387069' ,
            Formule: 'Postpaid' ,
            January: 0 ,
            February: 0 ,
            March: 54324.00 ,
            April: 54585.00 ,
            May: 0 ,
            June: 956418.00 ,
            July: 107655.00 ,
            August: 0.00 ,
            September: 0.00 ,
            October: 0.00 ,
            November: 0.00 ,
            December: 0 ,
            Total: 0 },
            { Id: '', 
            Noms: '', 
            Fonction: '', 
            Departement: '', 
            GSM: '695175511' ,
            Formule: 'Postpaid' ,
            January: 0 ,
            February: 0 ,
            March: 0.00 ,
            April: 0.00 ,
            May: 0 ,
            June: 0.00 ,
            July: 0.00 ,
            August: 0.00 ,
            September: 0.00 ,
            October: 0.00 ,
            November: 0.00 ,
            December: 0 ,
            Total: 0 },
            { Id: '', 
            Noms: '', 
            Fonction: '', 
            Departement: '', 
            GSM: '695206511' ,
            Formule: 'Prepaid' ,
            January: 0 ,
            February: 0 ,
            March: 22642.00 ,
            April: 22642.00 ,
            May: 0 ,
            June: 22642.00 ,
            July: 0.00 ,
            August: 0.00 ,
            September: 0.00 ,
            October: 0.00 ,
            November: 0.00 ,
            December: 0 ,
            Total: 0 },
            { Id: '', 
            Noms: '', 
            Fonction: '', 
            Departement: '', 
            GSM: '696290337' ,
            Formule: 'Prepaid' ,
            January: 0 ,
            February: 0 ,
            March: 24151.00 ,
            April: 24151.00 ,
            May: 0 ,
            June: 0.00 ,
            July: 0.00 ,
            August: 0.00 ,
            September: 0.00 ,
            October: 0.00 ,
            November: 0.00 ,
            December: 0 ,
            Total: 0 },
            { Id: '', 
            Noms: '', 
            Fonction: '', 
            Departement: '', 
            GSM: '699680185' ,
            Formule: 'Postpaid' ,
            January: 0 ,
            February: 0 ,
            March: 461115.00 ,
            April: 1031505.00 ,
            May: 0 ,
            June: 787023.00 ,
            July: 1263012.00 ,
            August: 634868.00 ,
            September: 907004.00 ,
            October: 1025869.00 ,
            November: 1152374.00 ,
            December: 0 ,
            Total: 3720115 },
            { Id: '', 
            Noms: '', 
            Fonction: '', 
            Departement: '', 
            GSM: '696574843' ,
            Formule: 'Prepaid' ,
            January: 0 ,
            February: 0 ,
            March: 30189.00 ,
            April: 30189.00 ,
            May: 0 ,
            June: 30189.00 ,
            July: 30189.00 ,
            August: 30189.00 ,
            September: 22642.00 ,
            October: 22642.00 ,
            November: 22642.00 ,
            December: 0 ,
            Total: 98115 },
            { Id: '', 
            Noms: '', 
            Fonction: '', 
            Departement: '', 
            GSM: '696630511' ,
            Formule: 'Postpaid' ,
            January: 0 ,
            February: 0 ,
            March: 22642.00 ,
            April: 22642.00 ,
            May: 0 ,
            June: 22642.00 ,
            July: 22642.00 ,
            August: 22642.00 ,
            September: 487.00 ,
            October: 20779.00 ,
            November: 22628.00 ,
            December: 0 ,
            Total: 66536 },

      ];
      $scope.getTotal = function(type) {
           var total = 0;
            angular.forEach($scope.Annuaire, function(el) {
                total += el[type];
            });
            return total;
        };
        $scope.sum=function(item){
            return item.June + item.July + item.August + item.September;
        }
});
```

When the js concole is opened and I update the page, I can see the values :
[image]

Here is the console :
[image]

I noticed that by removing the noFractionCurrency filter, the problem is solved.

Comment: please provide your html and js

Comment: Please give the raw HTML source, not your PHP script, which is not relevant. You can right click the page, then choose "View Page Source", and copy the relevant parts from there. Something in your JS is probably breaking poor IE, which you might see in its Console.

Comment: Update done! You can have a look at it now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard any idea ?

Comment: Nope, can't see anything abnormal on first look. What does the Console say? Any errors in there?

Comment: No error on console, on the other side I just noticed that, as soon as I update the page while the js console is opened, the values finally appear!!!

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this issue is by removing or commenting this line to my js script :

```
//console.log(amount, value);
```

It is somehow blocking IE to display the data. I do not understand why.
But it works good.